Issue with forward propagation output mismatch despite correct initialization and parameter shapes in neural network model
I am working on a neural network assignment for my course, and I am facing an issue where the forward propagation output (A2) does not match the expected results. Despite using the correct initialization of parameters and ensuring the correct parameter shapes, the output does not match the expected values from the grader function. I’m using a fixed testing framework that I cannot modify (as required by the course).
I am implementing a basic neural network with one hidden layer. The grader function compares the output of my model (specifically A2) against expected values, and it fails due to a mismatch in the output of the forward propagation step. The issue seems to be with the initialization of the parameters or how forward propagation is being performed, but I cannot modify the testing framework itself.
CODE:

Parameter Initialization Function (initialize_parameters):

def initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y):
    np.random.seed(2)
    W1 = np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) * 0.01  # n_h=4, n_x=2
    b1 = np.zeros((4, 1))
    W2 = np.random.randn(n_y, n_h) * 0.01  # n_y=1, n_h=4
    b2 = np.zeros((1, 1))
    parameters = {"W1": W1, "b1": b1, "W2": W2, "b2": b2}
    return parameters

Here, W1 has a shape of (4, 2), b1 has a shape of (4, 1), W2 has a shape of (1, 4), and b2 has a shape of (1, 1).

Forward Propagation Function (forward_propagation):

def forward_propagation(X, parameters):
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    b1 = parameters['b1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    b2 = parameters['b2']
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + b1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)
    assert A2.shape == (1, X.shape[1])
    cache = {"Z1": Z1, "A1": A1, "Z2": Z2, "A2": A2}
    return A2, cache

(kindly note that I have already defined the sigmoid function correctly in a function beforehand)
Here, the shape of A2 after forward propagation is (1, 3) (which seems correct based on the input size of (2, 3)).
However, the output of A2 does not match the expected values for the test case. The expected A2 output should be:
A2 = [[0.21292656 0.21274673 0.21295976]]
But I’m getting:
A2 = [[0.21442387 0.21436745 0.21442857]]
Testing Framework:

The grader function is pre-defined and compares A2 against expected values. I cannot modify the grader function or the test cases provided by the course.
The grader function expects A2 to match exactly with the expected output. I have tried various random seeds (e.g., np.random.seed(42)), but the output still does not match.

What I've Tried:

Ensured that the shapes of the weight matrices and bias vectors are correct.
Printed out the shapes of Z1, A1, Z2, and A2 at each step.
Used np.random.seed(42) and np.random.seed(2) in the initialization, but it hasn’t resolved the issue.

Could there be an issue with the random initialization affecting the consistency of the output?

it is not clear what you're expecting from the seed. it must not be random. you have to use the exact same seed as the course if you want the same result

The tester function has np.random.seed(2), hence I've used the same before calling np.random.rand() for my weights. Still doesn't work. @folengateis

you should call seed just once at the start of the script. and you said that 2 and 42 were random, you must use the same seed that was used to generate the "expected values"

i see no reference to a seed, so if the question relies on repeating an experiment to produce the same outcome, this would fail.  Look at this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator
